# Algebraic methods to compute the cohomology ring of the complex topology of a variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, complex-geometry

Suppose $V$ is an affine (resp. projective) subvariety of the affine (resp. projective) space $\mathbb A_\mathbb C^n$ (resp. $\mathbb P_\mathbb C^n$) with vanishing ideal $I\subseteq\mathbb C[X_1,\dotsc,X_n]$ (resp. homogeneous vanishing ideal $I\subseteq\mathbb C[X_0,\dotsc,X_n]$), and $V(\mathbb C)$ is its set of closed points with complex topology. Is there any good method to recover the cohomology ring $H^\bullet(V(\mathbb C),\mathbb Z)$ from ideal theoretic quantities of $I$?

Just for the simplest case, $V=\mathbb P_\mathbb C^n$, we have $H^\bullet(V(\mathbb C),\mathbb Z)=\mathbb Z[X]/(X^{n+1})$. So far, I've heard two methods to compute it, via spectral sequence or by induction. I don't know whether algebraic methods will cover this simple case.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: When the variety is smooth (and in more general cases, but it becomes very complicated...) you can compute the de Rham cohomology of the underlying complex manifold  as the cohomology of the "algebraic de Rham" compklex, built out of Kahler forms. You can find this explained in a great paper by Hartshorne. This is a purely algebraic method to compute.

Comment: Spectral sequences and induction? For $\mathbb{CP}^n$ you can just explicitly write down a CW structure which only has cells in even dimensions and use cellular (co)homology.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Thanks. If it's a complex manifold, there's a CW decomposition of $V(\mathbb C)$ with only even dimensional cells (cf. Milnor's *Morse Theory*) and therefore the cohomology is torsion-free, and one can recover $\mathbb Z$-cohomology from $\mathbb R$-cohomology? Thanks for the reference.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Induction method is concerned with the embedding $\mathbb P_\mathbb C^{n-1}\to\mathbb P_\mathbb C^n$, and the spectral sequence associates to $S^1\to S^{2n+1}\to\mathbb P_\mathbb C^n$. Right, $\mathbb P_\mathbb C^n=e^0\cup e^2\cup\dotsb\cup e^{2n}$, but I don't know whether the cup product is easily computed.

Comment: @Frank: fair enough. For the cup product you can use (differential-geometric, not algebro-geometric) intersection theory: once you believe that the cup product corresponds to such-and-such transverse intersections you can just explicitly compute all such intersections, which ends up being some straightforward linear algebra.

Comment: @FrankScience, have you considered the case of curves?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez For projective algebraic curves, it's fairly easy since the geometric genus $2g-2$ is the only topological invariant.

Comment: @FrankScience, my point was, you said that there is  CW structure with cells only in even dimension. How does that work for curves?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Thanks. I was wrong. The original theorem is on holomorphic submanifolds of $\mathbb C^n$, not for projective ones.

Comment: But any projective curve will become affine once you delete one point...

Comment: There is a generating function for the hodge numbers of a complete intersection.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Now I understood some of these papers but it seems to me that algebraic de Rham cohomology (Hodge completed derived de Rham cohomology, or if it's embedded in a smooth variety, the de Rham cohomology completed along the subvariety) at best, computes the Betti cohomology with coefficients in $\mathbb C$. The torsion is more subtle.